# Cannot create a .jsp file in Spring inspite if having all dependancies?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, web

Been trying this since a while now, already have the Spring web, H2 and JDBC dependencies.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ST4 you need to install "Eclipse Enterprise Java and Web Developer Tools" from the Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

To write jsp files in spring we need add jsp or jstl dependency in pom.xml
Refer: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api

add appropriate dependency version and try running the application.